# Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно, используя цикл, перебрать свойства объекта и вывести информацию о каждой планете на экран

Tags: javascript

```js
let planets = {
  planet1: {
    name: 'Меркурий',
    diameter: 4880,
    distance: 58000000
  },
  planet2: {
    name: 'Венера',
    diameter: 12104,
    distance: 108000000
  },
  planet3: {
    name: 'Земля',
    diameter: 12742,
    distance: 384467
  },
  planet4: {
    name: 'Марс',
    diameter: 3390,
    distance: 55000000
  },
  planet5: {
    name: 'Нептун',
    diameter: 49528,
    distance: 4500000000000
  },
  planet6: {
    name: 'Юпитер',
    diameter: 139882,
    distance: 108000000
  },
  planet7: {
    name: 'Сатурн',
    diameter: 116464,
    distance: 1195000000
  },
  planet8: {
    name: 'Уран',
    diameter: 51118,
    distance: 583000
  }
}

for (let key in planets) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${planets[key]}`);
}
```

Comment: `${planets[key].name}` либо `${planets[key]['name']}` и таким образом можете работать со всеми свойствами объекта или сделать ему деструктуризацию, как Вам будет удобно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать цикл по [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

```js
let planets = {
  planet1: {
    name: 'Меркурий',
    diameter: 4880,
    distance: 58000000
  },
  planet2: {
    name: 'Венера',
    diameter: 12104,
    distance: 108000000
  },
  planet3: {
    name: 'Земля',
    diameter: 12742,
    distance: 384467
  } 
}

for (const [key, data] of Object.entries(planets)) {
  console.log(`${key} - Название: ${data.name}, диаметр: ${data.diameter}, расстояние: ${data.distance}`);
}
```